# How to access MATLAB installed on a server?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

A pretty basic question. The MATLAB is installed on a linux based server. I have windows 7 installed on my system. I want to access MATLAB, how do i do that?

Shall i install some virtual machine or is there a simpler way? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB will run on Windows 7, so you could just install it on your Win7 machine. The other more complicated route would be to run a VNC client on the Win7 box and a matching server on the Linux side. Then you can have access to the remote linux desktop from Win7.

Reference [here.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-do-i-run-a-remote-linux-desktop-in-windows/)

Comment: You can also run MATLAB over SSH, if you run it in headless mode. If you can do X-forwarding, you can even open the editor, command history, figure windows, etc.

Comment: The license bought by our company is installed linux based server and i have to get access it to it somehow from my windows machine in order either to install it or get access to it.

I dont know how to access it first. :(

Comment: @imagine2200 Using matlab remotely via VNC is perfectly suitable. Colleagues told me that it's fine via X-forwarding too, but I did not try it myself though.